# Async NamedPipes in case of multiple pipe server instances

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, named-pipes

I'm using code from [**this article**](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/492231/Csharp-Async-Named-Pipes) with only difference that **maxNumberOfServerInstances** is set to **-1** (number of server instances with the same pipe name is limited only by system resources) in **NamedPipeServerStream** constructor

Async Listen Method [Listen Server Class]:

```
class PipeServer
{
string _pipeName;

public void Listen(string PipeName)
{
    try
    {
        // Set to class level var so we can re-use in the async callback method
        _pipeName = PipeName;
        // Create the new async pipe 
        NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(PipeName, 
           PipeDirection.In, -1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

        // Wait for a connection
        pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection
        (new AsyncCallback(WaitForConnectionCallBack), pipeServer);
    }
    catch (Exception oEX)
    {   ...   }
}

private void WaitForConnectionCallBack(IAsyncResult iar)
{
    try
    {
        // Get the pipe
        NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = (NamedPipeServerStream)iar.AsyncState;
        // End waiting for the connection
        pipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(iar);

        // Read the incoming message
        byte[] buffer = new byte[255];           
        pipeServer.Read(buffer, 0, 255);

        // Convert byte buffer to string
        string stringData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        ...

        // Kill original sever and create new wait server
        pipeServer.Close();
        pipeServer = null;
        pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(_pipeName, PipeDirection.In, 
           -1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

        // Recursively wait for the connection again and again....
        pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(
           new AsyncCallback(WaitForConnectionCallBack), pipeServer);
    }
    catch
    { ... }
}
}
```

Async Send Method [PipeClient Class]

```
class PipeClient
{
public void Send(string SendStr, string PipeName, int TimeOut = 1000)
{
    try
    {
        NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream
           (".", PipeName, PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

        // The connect function will indefinitely wait for the pipe to become available
        // If that is not acceptable specify a maximum waiting time (in ms)
        pipeStream.Connect(TimeOut);            

        byte[] _buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SendStr);
        pipeStream.BeginWrite
        (_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(AsyncSend), pipeStream);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException oEX)
    {    ...        }
}

private void AsyncSend(IAsyncResult iar)
{
    try
    {
        // Get the pipe
        NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = (NamedPipeClientStream)iar.AsyncState;

        // End the write
        pipeStream.EndWrite(iar);
        pipeStream.Flush();
        pipeStream.Close();
        pipeStream.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception oEX)
    {    ...         }
}
}
```

And I have two WinForms applications: server only have **Listen** button (clicking results in Listen method call), client has textBox for text input and **Send** button (clicking results in Send method call).

I do the following:

1. start multiple copies of server application (as the result - multiple instances of **NamedPipeServerStream** with the same pipe name are created)
2. click **Listen** button in each of them
3. start client application
4. click **Send** button

That results in receiving message by **only one server application** (that one, whose **Listen** button was clicked first). If I click **Send** button one more time - message is received by second-clicked server application. So instances receive messages in order of pressing **Listen** button on them and that repeats in cycle (but I'm not 100% sure that such order **will be the same under all conditions**).

Such behavior is strange for me: I've expected message to be received by **all instances at the same time**.

Could someone explain me why it is happening in such way?

How can I deliver message to all instaces with one **Send** button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally I've found a solution (don't sure it's optimal - but it's working). It is based on using **NamedPipeClientStream.NumberOfServerInstances**.

```
public void Send(string SendStr, string PipeName, int TimeOut = 1000)
{
    try
    {
        NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream
          (".", PipeName, PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

        // The connect function will indefinitely wait for the pipe to become available
        // If that is not acceptable specify a maximum waiting time (in ms)
        pipeStream.Connect(TimeOut); 

        int _serverCount = pipeStream.NumberOfServerInstances; 

        byte[] _buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SendStr);
        pipeStream.BeginWrite(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(AsyncSend), pipeStream);

        //there is more than 1 server present
        for (int i = 1; i < _serverCount; i++)
            {
                //create another client copy and use it
                NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream2 = new NamedPipeClientStream
                (".", PipeName, PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

                pipeStream2.Connect(TimeOut);

                byte[] buffer2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SendStr);
                pipeStream2.BeginWrite(buffer2, 0, buffer2.Length, AsyncSend, pipeStream2);
            }
    }
    catch (TimeoutException oEX)
    {    ...        }
}
```

Note that this code doensn't handle situation when NumberOfServerInstances changes while cycle is running (sudden server instance closing, etc.)

**BTW** Don't have any idea why MSDN suggests to use

```
 // Kill original sever and create new wait server
 pipeServer.Close();
 pipeServer = null;
 pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(_pipeName, PipeDirection.In, 
    -1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

 // Recursively wait for the connection again and again....
 pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(
   new AsyncCallback(WaitForConnectionCallBack), pipeServer);
```

Instead I've tested simply disconnecting current client

```
pipeServer.Disconnect();

// Recursively wait for the connection again and again....
pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(
   new AsyncCallback(WaitForConnectionCallBack), pipeServer);
```

and it worked for me the same way.

Comment: I'm not an expert but my guess is that the `pipeServer = null;` logic is an attempt to "help" the garbage collector. However, since it implements IDisposable a "using" block is probably more useful.