# Simple Interprocess-Communication with multiple listeners

Tags: java, c#, c++, cross-platform, ipc

In a project I have one master-application (C#) that controls several child-applications.

Those child-applications will be written in C#, Java, C++ and python.
And, which makes it more difficult, there can be multiple instances of the same child-applications.

This can be illustrated like:

[image]

Right now I thought of `NamedPipes`, but this will not work with multiple instances, because they would all listen to the same pipe (at the moment I have no way of telling the child-process which pipename to use).

Is there an easy and lightweight way of one way communication which is not dependent on platform (or at least available in the languages mentioned above)?

Comment: If the master application starts the children could it just pass them  messages as strings on standard in?

Comment: You should have updated your original question rather than asking a very similar new one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427692/namedpipe-multiple-servers

Comment: The original question is about named pipes, which seems to be unsolvable. So I asked this more general question.

Comment: Yes, they are started by the master-application. String will be fine. Have to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

How about usual Client/server approach?
You can choose (or implement) the protocol yourself depending on your requirements.

Comment: Each child-application is be a server and communication is somewhat "heavy-weight" from the master-applications view.

Comment: I was rather thinking that each child will be the client as it is easier for the child app to connect to master/server app.
Then it does not matter what is the server and what is the client as the IO channels are bi-directional. One well designed server is more than capable of serving hundreds of clients...

Answer (score 1):

You can use sockets, which is pretty much language agnostic, and will even work great if you decide to move your process to another machine.

You can also take a look at [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/)